# checkbox adds value to the next input in a table

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a table with a field for default quantity.
I then have dozens of rows of items, if a user clicks checkbox, i want to take the default value and add it to the qty input of that row.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type='text' id='defQty' name='defQty' size='4'></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='itemsCB[]' class='itemActivate'></th>
    <th><input type='text' name='qtys[]' size='3' class='qty'></th>
</tr>
```

is my table..

my jquery:

```
$('.itemActivate').change( function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var qty = $('#defQty').val();
        $(this).nextAll('input:first').val(qty);
    }
});
```

in this code, nothing happens....

Comment: Your ```$('#defQty')``` has not the ```value``` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.nextAll()` fetches siblings. Your `.itemActivate` checkbox has no siblings.

Consider getting the parent row using `.closest()`, and finding the input within using `.find()`:

```js
$('.itemActivate').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var qty = $('#defQty').val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find("input.qty").val(qty);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Default qty:</td>
    <td><input type='text' id='defQty' name='defQty' size='4'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='itemsCB[]' class='itemActivate'></th>
    <th><input type='text' name='qtys[]' size='3' class='qty'></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='itemsCB[]' class='itemActivate'></th>
    <th><input type='text' name='qtys[]' size='3' class='qty'></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='itemsCB[]' class='itemActivate'></th>
    <th><input type='text' name='qtys[]' size='3' class='qty'></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the correct methods to use are: [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

You may also want to **reset** the `.qty` input elements in case the corresponding checkbox is **unchecked**. The following line will do just that:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.qty').val( this.checked ? qty: "" );
```

See demo below.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.itemActivate').change( function() {
    var qty = $('#defQty').val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty').val( this.checked ? qty: "" );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>DEFAULT VALUE</th><td><input type='text' id='defQty' name='defQty' size='4' value="79"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='itemsCB[]' class='itemActivate'></th>
    <th><input type='text' name='qtys[]' size='3' class='qty'></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='itemsCB[]' class='itemActivate'></th>
    <th><input type='text' name='qtys[]' size='3' class='qty'></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='itemsCB[]' class='itemActivate'></th>
    <th><input type='text' name='qtys[]' size='3' class='qty'></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='itemsCB[]' class='itemActivate'></th>
    <th><input type='text' name='qtys[]' size='3' class='qty'></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='itemsCB[]' class='itemActivate'></th>
    <th><input type='text' name='qtys[]' size='3' class='qty'></th>
</tr>
</table>
```